# Sum of Hilbert spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

For various reasons I need to define the following space
$$\hat{H}=\{u\mid u=f+g, \;f\in H^{2,-s}(\mathbb{R}^3),\; g\in L^{2,-s}(\mathbb{R}^3)\}$$
where
$$L^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3)=\{f|(1+\vert\cdot\vert^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}f(\cdot)\in L^2 \}$$
e
$$H^{2,s}=\{f|D^\alpha f\in L^{2,s}, 0\leq\vert\alpha\vert\leq 2\}$$
per ogni $s\in\mathbb{R}$.
If I define the norm
$$\Vert u\Vert_*:=\Vert f\Vert_{H^{2,-s}(\mathbb{R}^3)}+\Vert g\Vert_{L^{2,-s}(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$
the space $\hat{H}$ is complete.using the completeness of the Hilbert space $H^{2,-s}$ e $L^{2,-s}$.
Is $\hat{H}$ an Hilbert space too?

Comment: Before worrying about whether this is a Hilbert space, have you shown that your proposed norm is well-defined? There could be several ways to write $u = f+g$, where $f$ and $g$ are in your original spaces. (You should probably also tell us exactly what you mean by $H^{2,-s}$ and $L^{2,s}$. Notation for function spaces vary quite a lot.)

Comment: Without looking into the details here: A common construction in a case like this would be to take $\|u\| = \inf \|f\|_1 + \|g\|_2$ where the infimum is taken over all possible decompositions $u=f+g$.

Comment: @mrf you have reason. I can solve the problem without defining a new norm and I can consider for $u$ simply the norm in $L^{2,-s}\subset H^{2,-s}$ isn't it?